# Is there a function in C++ that will get you the address space of all the pointers that point to that node?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Say we have a linked list of nodes: A->B->C->D.
Is there a function in C++ that will get you pointers to that node?
Like, `pointerTo(B) would yield A->next.`

Comment: You have to know how to make a post. There is no default function to point to node. May be `Macro` can solve your problem.

Comment: The short answer is: no, there's nothing like that, whatsoever, in C++.

Comment: Pointers are one way only. No object can know what other objects may be pointing at it. The book-keeping required to track who is pointing at what would be crippling in all but the most modest of programs.

Comment: The c++ philosophy would be to solve your 'problem' by creating a class. Perhaps as part (member attribute) of your classes A, .. D, such that when updating a pointer in one object, the function also reaches over and touches the other. Obviously there is a cost, but perhaps building the links (with a back link) is rare (done once?) in your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such function does not exist and could not exist in C++, since C++ does not have a virtual machine. This could be a part of a garbage collector, but C++ does not have one. Collecting this kind of information would contradict zero-overhead principle of the language.

Comment: If you're looking for the parent of B, you'll have to store the pointer to A manually.

Comment: Seeing this question in retrospect... haha such a funny question! I now understand the downvotes! I didn't even know what overhead was rofl or virtual machine.